# Exportation is not working through another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I want to export variable in script(`details.sh`) from different location in another script(`3funding.sh`) but unable to do although I am giving correct command in `3funding.sh` file.

Question is, I am able to do it manually like getting out of `3funding.sh` and executing below command:

```
. ./{path}/details.sh
```

but I don't want to get out from `3funding.sh` file as there are more than 10 scripts running for my project.

Can somebody help me with this as why variable is not getting exported from another script and from other location on the same server.

Below entries I have tested in details.sh

```
$ cat details.sh
#!/bin/bash

qlid_aa185="aa185"
name_anshul="anshul"
qlid_dk185="dk185"
name_dibya="dibya"
qlid_ff44="ff44"
name_ffff="ffff"
```

Need `echo $qlid_aa185` to show the result `aa185` without any manual exportation.

Comment: Please format your code properly, so that it is easier to read. Did you post the **complete** *details.sh*, or only the first few lines?

Comment: I just want to take value of one variable from one script(details.sh) to another(3funding.sh). The command is working manually but not, when I try to execute within the another script(3funding.sh).

Comment: In this case, you should certainly not source the whole script, as it might do things you don't want to be done. The cleanest solution would be to put the setting of the variable into a separate file, which you are sourcing from both, details.sh and 3funding.sh.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy explanation. Do you want to import variables to `3funding.sh` from the `details.sh` script? If I understand it correctly, than you need to do the following:

details.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export qlid_aa185="aa185"
export name_anshul="anshul"
export qlid_dk185="dk185"
export name_dibya="dibya"
export qlid_ff44="ff44"
export name_ffff="ffff"
```

3funding.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source <path>/details.sh

echo "Imported variables:"
echo "- qlid_aa185: $qlid_aa185"
echo "- qlid_ff44: $qlid_ff44"
```

If you run the script `3funding.sh` from the example above you will receive:

```
Imported variables:
- qlid_aa185: aa185
- qlid_ff44: ff44
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but it worked for first entry and for remaining entries it is not working and showing blank result.